# Setting up Amazon elastic beanstalk to be accessible through fixed ip address(not CNAME)

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, nat, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elastic-ip

I want to deploy my app to multi-container elastic beanstalk to be able to point my A-record to some fixed ip connected to it(somehow).

I've read related questions(like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475287/elastic-ip-on-application-deployed-using-elastic-beanstalk)) and understand that it can be achieved by:

**Tackling www redirects**

Not an option as our production website is historically resolved without www and adding redirects will negatively influence our SEO

**Transferring domain to Route53 as it has aliases feature**

Not an option due to legal and business issues.

**Using single-container instance**

Not an option as auto-scaling is primary feature why we want to use moreover each redeploy will destroy EIP.

So I'm thinking about other possible solutions. I've been able to found some fragmented details about that is possible to user separate NAT for outgoing [traffic](https://serverfault.com/questions/625166/static-ip-address-for-outgoing-traffic-from-aws-autoscaling-group). Is it possible to setup  NAT with fixed(elastic) IP to be able to accept incoming traffic(both http+s) and redirect it further to elb? How that should be achieved in details (I suppose some kind of apache/nginx and proxy_pass requests to elasticbeanstalk dns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've pretty much listed all the available options, as I see it you'll have to go with one of your first two options if you want to be able to take advantage of the great features that AWS offer (such as elastic load balancing and auto scaling).

The NAT thing you mention would probably be some sort of reverse proxy (?), but you encounter the same issue there. You want the proxy layer to scale automatically too, but you won't be able to achieve it since you need static IPs (...and you're back to square one).

I've been tackling these issues myself, and I've always ended up setting up a hosted zone in Route53 and changing the name servers on registrar level to point against it.